# Problema ao setar entidade no httppost usando Java

Tags: java, rest, http-post

Estou a horas tentando substituir uma biblioteca, alguém pode me ajudar?
Acredito que por falta de compatibilidade de jar, meu sistema não está aceitando a seguinte linha de código:

```
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```

Ou seja, o problema está na hora de setar a entidade no httpPost. Ele simplesmente não roda depois dessa linha. Como entidade, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
```

Eu gostaria de saber se alguém sabe alguma forma de setar a entidade de outra forma, ou se, existe outra biblioteca que eu possa usar ao invés da HttpPost.
Não tenho experiência em serviços Rest e por isso a dúvida. Já busquei em diversos locais mas não achei nada que me ajude.

Quanto ao jar, estou usando httpclient e httpcore e ao testar várias versões não adiantou:
Versões sem sucesso:
4.5.13,
4.5.12,
4.2.3,
4.5.10,
4.4.

obs.: Captura do erro: org/apache/http/HttpEntity

Alguém pode ajudar? Desde já agradeço!!!

Comment: você colocou ali que a captura do erro é "org/apache/http/HttpEntity" mas qual a descrição do erro?

Comment: Lucas, não sei o porquê mas ao capturar os erros das seguintes formas o retorno são apenas esses:

    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());

    org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/HttpClients
    [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@42bfc967
    org/apache/hc/client5/http/impl/classic/HttpClients

Obs.: Estou tentando a versão 5 agora... e nada de novo